# Where clause when using XML in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am currently using a XML data type in a SQL table

My datatable looks like this

```
Id | Name | Surname | Title  | Location | Artist |
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | xxx  | abc     | def    | London   | XML    |
2  | xxx  | abc     | def    | Oslo     | XML    |
3  | xxx  | abc     | def    | New York | XML    |
```

My XML file looks like this

```
<song category="gaming">
<title>Valentine's Day</title>
<artist-main>Fatfinger</artist-main>
<artist-featured>Slimthumb</artist-featured>
<year>2013</year>
<price>29.99</price>
<album>Gamestain</album>
<albumimg>http://download.gamezone.com/uploads/image/data/875338/halo-4.jpg</albumimg>
<songurl>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J0ABq9TnCw</songurl>
```

Now to get the record depending upon the artist I am using a query which is

```
SELECT 
Id, Name, Surname, Title 
FROM 
DATA 
WHERE 
Artist Like '%Fatfinger%' -- (this is user input)
```

Is this is the right approach in querying XML data in SQL or are there any built in functions in SQL that can handle XML. I am new to SQL.

Comment: Wich RDBM's are you using, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc. Retag your question so it has a better visibility and therefore get some attention

Comment: Also, check your XML sintax, line 3 and 4 does not have a correct closing tag. Should be `artist-main` and `artist-feature`. And I guess there is a closing `</song>` tag at the end.

Comment: @Yaroslav I am using MS SQL 2012

Comment: @John I just had a look at the link. Thanks but found it a little bit advanced. I have just begin to use sql less than 10 hrs :)

Comment: @FloodGravemind, no problem. The point really is that you're not using SQL at all when it comes to XML fields. You're actually using a form of XPath. That question has links that explain how it works. You *can* treat the XML as text and use string manipulation techniques like you're doing in your example, but it's usually better to use XML-specific tools on XML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @table table (
Id int, Name varchar(50), Surname varchar(50), 
Title  varchar(50), Location varchar(50), Artist xml)

insert into @table (Id, Name, Surname, Title, Location , Artist )
values(1, 'xxx', 'abc', 'def', 'London', '<song category="gaming"></song>
<title>Valentines Day</title>
<artist-main>Fatfinger</artist-main>
<artist-featured>Slimthumb</artist-featured>
<year>2013</year>
<price>29.99</price>
<album>Gamestain</album>
<albumimg>http://download.gamezone.com/uploads/image/data/875338/halo-4.jpg</albumimg>
<songurl>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J0ABq9TnCw</songurl>')

SELECT Id, Name, Surname, Title 
FROM @table 
WHERE Artist.value('(/artist-main)[1]','varchar(max)') LIKE '%FatFinger%'
```

Comment: Are you going around answering all the xml sql questions :)

Comment: No :). I recently some learned xml, so I just knew the answer.

Comment: @Mike Can I use the "=" operator instead of "Like" in this statement? And one more thing what does the "[1]" signify? Thanks

Comment: Getting  - Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the .value function.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Surname, Title 
FROM DATA 
WHERE Artist.value('(/song/artist-main)[1]','varchar(max)') LIKE '%FatFinger%'
```

Comment: Can I use the "=" operator instead of "Like" in this statement? And one more thing what does the "[1]" signify? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can.  Just remove the wild-card characters.  Also, [1] indicates that you're going to return the first value at that song/artist-main node.  That's what you want.  John M Gant's link above mentions that too.